# How to split integers within a two-dimensional list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, split

Say I have:

```
data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

And I want to define a function that will take this one list argument, 'data', and be able to separate the integers within the first and second instances.

After, it needs to take each of those integers that shared each instance and subtract it from one another like this:

```
1 - 2 (which would be -1)
3 - 4 (which would be -1)
```

And then take those numbers and finds the product and returns the final integer (-1 * -1) = 1

Kind of lost as to how I would go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with unpacking:

```
data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

d1, d2 = data
a, b, c, d = *d1, *d2
res = (a - b) * (c - d)

print(res)
# 1
```

If there are arbitrary number of sublists, you would better iterate:

```
lst = []
for d in data:
    a, b = d
    lst.append(a - b)

res = 1
for x in lst:
    res *= x      

print(res)
# 1
```

Comment: Interesting! That definitely worked, but is there any other more simple way that uses conditional logic and such?

Also, can you explain what is going on here? So essentially with the d1, d2 = data, we're able to split the lists into "buckets" into d1 and d2 respectively? And then with the a, b, c, d = *d1, *d2 we're able to create "variables" for each of those integers? Blowing my mind lol. So is there a term for the '*' that goes before the d1 and d2?  Thanks for your input btw!

Comment: @CodingNoob, conditional logic? What is the condition you want to bring in?

Comment: Or, maybe not conditional logic but maybe some for or while loops, sorry. I guess I'd want to define this function to be more adaptable. Such as, if in another case, the user wanted to pass through data but this time it has 4 lists of 2 integers. So essentially, how would we build the original function in a way that we don't have to redo the code to match the number of lists within the data each time but instead the user can put any number of lists within the data list and it would still calculate everything? (Assuming it's still a two-dimensional list though). Sorry if I'm not making senselol

Comment: Can you guarantee that the elements in each list is still two?

Comment: Yes definitely. So it'll always be one list that consists of pairs of integer lists. So maybe like [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] but it would never be [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just edited my answer.